# Change one field from a key in two related tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables related by a composite primary key and one of the fields in the key needs to be changed.  Can this be done without deleting the relationship and then re-establishing it after the value is changed?

```
myTable
    myTableID   CPK
    firstField  CPK  this needs to be changed
    secondField CPK

myOtherTable
    myOtherTableID
    myTableID CFK   this needs to be changed here
    firstField CFK
    secondField CFK
```

How can I update `firstField` from both tables simultaneously?

Comment: You can set the foreign key constraint to `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and the change in the base table will be reflects in the foreign tables.  *(Do this to all your foreign tables.)*

Comment: Is on update cascade typically something that's standard procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read [this article](http://sqlandme.com/2011/08/08/sql-server-how-to-cascade-updates-and-deletes-to-related-tables/) which explains how to make updates and transactions reflect on related tables.

Use the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` fro your specific case.

Hope this helps